# How to keep nav menu highlighted after click using js in sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created a nav menu in Wordpress and placed it in sidebar.php in my child theme.

My nav menu is in the correct location and functions and looks as it should with the exception of the JS, which I have tried to get right but seem to be failing.

Each menu item takes you to a different page. I want the menu item to stay highlighted to show which page you are on once you have linked to that page. I have used CSS to highlight the li using :hover.

I cant work out how or where to place the js to keep it the menu highlighted.

1. Is my JS correct?
2. Where do I place it? directly in sidebar.php under the html? or somewhere else?

Thank you!

```js
$('.main-nav-list').on('click', function () {
                $('li.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');

            });
```

```css
.main-nav .main-nav-list li:hover {
 background-color: #323840;
 width: 150px;
 border-radius: 20px; 
}

.main-nav .main-nav-list li:active {
 background-color: #323840;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar sidebar-main <?php echo $sidebar_classes; ?>">
        <div class="inner-content widgets-container">
                <?php generated_dynamic_sidebar($sidebar_name);?>
<div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked main-nav">
<div class="main-nav-holder">
<ul class="main-nav-list">
<li class="active">
 <a id="sidebar-questions" href="/dwqa-questions">QUESTIONS</a>
</li>
<li class="">
 <a id="sidebar-ask" href="/dwqa-ask-question">ASK A QUESTION</a>
</li>
<li class="">
 <a id="sidebar-ama" href="/ask-me-anything">AMAs</a>
</li>
<li class="">
 <a id="sidebar-jobs" href="/jobs">JOBS</a>
</li>
<li class=“">
<a id="sidebar-find" href="/find-a-health-professional">FIND A HEALTH PRO</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: is there anything unclear in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40137559/2545680)

Comment: I have added your code between script tags in my sidebar.php file. But it doesnt work on the same page or the linked to page. Do I need to specify the pathway in `var pathname = document.location.pathname;` ? or just add as is?

Comment: add it as is. add ‛console.log(pathname)' under 'var pathname', what does it output?

Comment: My CSS shows now contains: `.main-nav .main-nav-list a:hover {
 background-color: #323840;
 width: 150px;
 border-radius: 20px; 
}
.main-nav .main-nav-list a:active {
 background-color: #323840;
}`

Comment: My sidebar.php contains: `</li>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    var pathname = console.log(pathname);
    $('.main-nav-list a').each(function () {
        var value = $(this).attr('href');
        if (pathname.indexOf(value) > -1) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            return false;
        }
    })
});
</script>

Comment: no, add the code snippet exactly how I showed it in my answer. If it still doesn't work, what does console.log show?

Comment: console.log shows: `GET http://52.209.186.138/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=kleo_bp_notifications_refresh&current=0 200 OK 2.24s  
jquery....=1.12.4 (line 4)`

Comment: that's not it, it's network request, and the log should say 'the pathname is:'

Comment: have your resolved your issue?

Comment: Not yet. I think I must be doing something very obviously wrong but I'm not sure what. I have placed your code between script tags in my sidebar.php and tried making changes to my CSS also but no change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126185/discussion-between-maximus-and-gavin-reynoldson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you don't use any router to remain on the same page. If so, then once a user clicks on any link, a browser will load completely new page and so this code of yours

```
$('.main-nav-list').on('click', function () {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

has no effect, because it modified the previous page that is now replaced by the new page. The one thing I think you can do on page load is to read `pathname` and highlight a corresponding link. Here is an example of how this can be done

```
<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        var pathname = document.location.pathname;
        console.log('the pathname is: ', pathname);

        jQuery('.main-nav-list a').each(function () {
            var value = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            if (pathname.indexOf(value) > -1) {
                jQuery(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
                return false;
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

And remove `active` class from all `li` elements in html.

I used `jQuery` instead of `$` because of this:

> "When WordPress’ jQuery is loaded, it uses compatibility mode, which
>   is a mechanism for avoiding conflicts with other language libraries.
>
> What this boils down to is that you can’t use the dollar sign directly
>   as you would in other projects. When writing jQuery for WordPress you
>   need to use jQuery instead. "

Comment: Thanky you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use this javascript function. This function will track the url from browser and will add the "active" class to the link.

Hope this will work for you.

Good Luck & Happy Coding.. :)

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/clients/">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>  

$(function() {
  $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Your jQuery click handler is binded to 'ul' tag which is incorrect, becouse inside callback function context of 'this' is represented by 'ul' instead of clicked li. Your code should looks like:

```
$('.main-nav-list li').on('click', function () {
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

2. If you are changing page with reloading you can store your navbar state in sessionStorage or get it from path.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/leonardoaraujocosta/jfkm4dtz/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu-sample">
  <li class="menu-item-sample active"><a href="http://google.com">link 1 here</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item-sample"><a href="http://google.com">link 2 here</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item-sample"><a href="http://google.com">link 3 here</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item-sample"><a href="http://google.com">link 4 here</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item-sample"><a href="http://google.com">link 5 here</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu-sample {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu-item-sample:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.menu-item-sample.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.menu-item-sample').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I hope to have helped in some way